# When reverting back to humanoid after being polymorphed, can a character have remaining movement speed in that turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, polymorph

A hag transforms my character into a frog, which gives my character a movement speed of 20 feet. Let's say that as a humanoid I would have had a speed of 30 feet instead. During my turn, I use the frog's full movement, before the hag uses a reaction to strike me with an Attack of Opportunity.The hit does enough damage so that I revert back to my original form.

**Do I now have 10 feet of movement remaining this turn, since I only used up 20 of my maximum speed?**

### Related

[How do changes to your speed affect your available movement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152345/how-do-changes-to-your-speed-affect-your-available-movement)

This question doesn't answer my question, since it doesn't a) give a clear yes or no to my question, and b) specifically address the context of having different movement speeds during my turn.

Comment: For clarification, are you suggesting that getting thrown into the wall was a reaction on the part of the Hag i.e. it is still your turn? Because if it was the Hag's turn when you got thrown there is no issue, you'd have 45 feet of movement at the beginning of your next turn.

Comment: @Steve, that is correct. The hag threw as a reaction. Will add it to avoid confusion.

Comment: A more generalizable scenario than the hag reaction (i.e. one I know exists) might be if you are hit with an opportunity attack that reduces your polymorphed form to 0 HP.

Comment: @Rykara, that answer hints towards how it works but requires too much digging and filtering without offering a clear yes or no. I'll generalize my Q, as suggested by V2Blast.

Comment: I think this question is more relevant: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152351/38502

Comment: @Lucasvw I agree, that Q is way more relevant since it addresses the "change of speed during a turn".

Comment: @Lucasvw I think my Q is a duplicate of the Q you shared: it gives the answers I seek, while covering a similar enough situation. Ty!