# Can the Female Steeders Leap twice if it dashes?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, movement

I was perusing beasts for my druid when I noticed that the Female Steeder from Out of the Abyss has this very intriguing ability.

> **Leap.** The Steeder can expend all its movement on its turn to jump up to 90 feet vertically or horizontally, provided that is speed is at least 30 feet.

**Can the Female Steeders Leap twice if it dashes?**

My reasoning is similar to this [answer about standing up and then dashing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83425/is-the-half-your-speed-used-in-standing-from-prone-your-normal-speed-or-curre/83441#83441).
The Steeder starts with 30' of movement, which it expends to Leap and then it dashes to get another 30' of movement and Leap again.

However, I am not sure if that reasoning should apply because the wording for standing up specifically says it "costs an amount of movement equal to *half your speed*", Whereas Leap doesn't say it "expends an amount of movement *equal to your speed*".

Comment: The statblock shown on DNDBeyond for the [female steeder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/female-steeder) seems to be worded differently: "***Extraordinary Leap.*** The distance of the steeder’s long jumps is tripled; every foot of its walking speed that it spends on the jump allows it to move 3 feet." But your wording does seem to match that in the physical OotA book... It seems the creature was republished in Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, and the DNDBeyond listing matches the ostensibly updated version of the statblock.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No, it cannot.

You quoted the relevant text already:

> Leap. The Steeder can expend **all its movement** on its turn to jump up to 90 feet vertically or horizontally, provided that is speed is at least 30 feet.

The rules on dashing (PHB, p. 192) state:

> When you take the Dash action, **you gain extra movement** for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers. With a speed of 30 feet, for example, you can move up to 60 feet on your turn if you dash.
>   Any increase or decrease to your speed changes this additional movement by the same amount. If your speed of 30 feet is reduced to 15 feet, for instance, you can move up to 30 feet this turn if you dash.

When you leap for the first time, you have to use all of your currently available movement which, at this moment, is all the movement you have on your turn.

Now, when you take the *Dash* action, it creates an issue - you now have movement left, but this movement is still on the same turn as the leap. Hence, you now have retroactively invalidated the first use of the *Leap*, since that requires you to use *all [your] movement on your turn*.

How to deal with this issue isn't clear from the rules, so your DM will have to make a ruling. I'd personally rule that the first leap isn't affected and you can now use the movement you gained from the *Dash* for moving.

What you *cannot* do with this movement is leaping a second time. Assuming you / the Steeder has a speed of 30 feet, you go through the following process during your turn:

1. You have 30/30 movement.
2. You use all of the movement on your turn (i.e. 30) to leap.
3. You now have 0/30 movement left.
4. You use the *Dash* action.
5. You now have 30/60 movement on your turn.
6. If you want to leap, you would have to use 60/60 movement (*all* the movement on your turn), but you only have 30. Therefore, you cannot leap.

Note that all of this is just rules-as-written. If your DM decides that a *Dash* allows a second leap, that's not too far-fetched, from a logical point of view.
Bear in mind, though, that some features might allow the steeder to use *Dash* as a bonus action, hence allowing it to jump 3*90 feet, i.e. 270, in one turn.

Comment: I can't help but think that "on its turn" just means "during its turn" and is meant prevent the Steeder from leaping on someone else's turn with a reaction.

Comment: You can't spend movement before you gain it.

Comment: @András Nor can you spend "*all* your movement" on the 2nd leap if you have already use some of it for the first.

Answer (score 16):

### It can use its dash for a second leap.

An updated version of Female Steeder now appears in Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes where the ability has been re-written. It now says:

> **Extraordinary Leap.** The distance of the steeder's long jumps is tripled; every foot of its walking speed that it spends on the jump
>   allows it to move 3 feet.

This is still oddly worded. Since no specific rule overrides the jumping rules, you use them as written. Normally, it would be able to leap its strength in feet with a 10 foot run-up, or half that from a standing jump. For regular creatures, each foot of jumping costs 1 foot of running. The second half of the ability as written sounds like you expend less of your running speed to make the same size jump, but it's a little more complex than that. The first half of the ability expressly states "The distance of the steeder's long jumps is tripled", which indicates that it can leap 3x its Str score on a running long jump and 1 1/2 its Str score in a standing jump.

A Female Steeder has a Str of 15. It can run 10 feet, expend 15 more feet to leap 45 feet, and still have 5 feet of running left over. Or it can do a standing jump of ~22 feet, expending 7 feet of running, and still have 23 feet for the remainder of its turn. DMs may want to round to 5 foot increments if using a battle mat and minis.

**I see no rule that says a creature cannot leap more than once in a single turn**. It has enough movement to make 4 standing jumps of 22 feet each, expending 7 feet of movement for each jump.

I also see no rule that says the movement granted by a Dash maneuver cannot be used for jumping. That whole process could be repeated, allowing the Female Steeder to make 2 running long jumps of 45 feet in a turn (+20 feet of running), or 8 standing jumps of 22 feet each (+4 feet total of running). The first option would be 110 feet covered in total, the second 180.

*Note, that I have rounded at different steps above. D&D doesn't handle some increments well. As a DM, I would let the running jumps go as written, but the standing jumps simply be 20 feet each and ignore the small change of running left over.*

Comment: I can't tell if your answer applies to the Female Steeder from OotA, MToF, or both.

Comment: @Ruse My assumption is that the MToF version is an updated and corrected write up of the OotA version, since the first was obviously ambiguous. I have edited the answer to make that clear.

Comment: If you clarify that you're not answering the question for the *Steeder* from OotA, but from MToF, I'll switch from down- to upvote. Currently, "It can use its dash for a second leap" is, RAW, simply wrong.

Comment: @PixelMaster I have edited the first line to make it more clear.

Comment: @PixelMaster Can you point out how using your dash for a second leap (for any creature) is wrong? AFAIK, the movement from a dash can be used for any kind of movement: swimming, climbing, or leaping. If there's a rule I'm missing, I'll revise the answer.

Comment: @Weaveworker89 Good point. I agree that as written, the ability simply changes the exchange rate for expended movement vs total feet covered. I'll revise.

Comment: @keithcurtis you're required to use **all** movement *on your turn* for the leap. Logic dictates that, therefore, you can't leap twice on your turn.

Comment: That wording is not in the MToF revision I have quoted. I've clarified that I am using the later text. The basic rules do not have the "all your movement" clause either. I am operating under the assumption that WotC has basically errata'd the ability, otherwise they would have re-named the creature.

Comment: @DanB Thanks, my wargame roots are showing...

Comment: One more thing: the rules text you quoted refers to long jumps specifically, but your answer seems to suggest that standing jumps are just as good.  Is this so?

Comment: @DanB The rules on jumping refer to "long jumps", "standing long jumps" and "high jumps". There is no "standing jump".

Comment: "[...] every foot of its walking speed that it spends on the jump allows it to move 3 feet." is the specific text that allows it to break the general rule. Jumping grants it tripled movement, so by jumping as it can, it is not exceeding it's speed, it's modifying it's speed.