# Can you Ready an action to knock someone prone after they've attacked?

Tags: dnd-5e, readied-action, prone

Could you ready the action: If an enemy attacks me then, once they've attacked, I will attempt to knock them prone.

If so it could be used if the distance between you and an enemy was too far to cross in one move, moving to 30 feet from them. Readying this action would give you advantage on your next attack, if successful, because the target would still be prone (not having had their turn yet to stand back up).

Comment: I assume you want this so they are prone at the start of your turn? Thus getting advantage? Be aware that in most (all?) cases just attacking twice properly gives better results.

Comment: @LioElbammalf what makes you expect you can *not* do this?

Comment: @SeriousBri Even if you're just by yourself, it can be worth it if you have Extra Attacks or bonus action attacks, or something like Sneak Attack that gives additional benefits for having advantage.

Comment: @enkryptor I wasn't sure if you could ready an action to trigger after being attacked.

Comment: @LioElbammalf: Given your assumption that they'll stay prone if you're successful, I assume what you're actually asking is whether you can Ready an action to trigger after someone's turn ends.

Comment: @V2Blast Yeah that just felt too much like meta gaming to specify that.

Comment: Not sure what the source of the confusion is here? Perhaps I misunderstood, but to me shoving after an attack seems to be the ideal time and it's a perceivable trigger that doesn't invoke any meta game ideas. If you make them move towards you before attacking, then they won't have enough movement left to stand up, and they won't be able to Dash because they'll have already used an action. So, they'll still be prone on your turn, and even better, it they have multi-attack then any subsequent attacks against will be at disadvantage.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, you can shove someone with a readied action.

The [ready action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) requires you to choose an action to take in response to a perceivable trigger.

And one of the actions available to you is the attack action, which can be used to  [shove](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature):

> Using the Attack action, you can make a special melee attack to shove a creature, [...] to knock it prone

I would also point out that you don't have to wait for the enemy creature to attack- you could choose a trigger of when the creature gets close enough to shove. However, as pointed out in the comments, this leaves the opportunity for the creature to use their action to Dash and stand back up.

Comment: If you shove before they've attacked wouldn't they be able to get back up?

Comment: Getting up is just an expenditure of movement.  They can get up before or after they attack, no matter when they get knocked down, if they have half their speed in movement left.

Comment: @LioElbammalf only if they have half their movement left, yes

Comment: @LioElbammalf although, thinking about this more, they could use the dash action to stand back up as well (but then they would have used up their action)

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83425/38502